# Retry Request.get() Python

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests

How do I retry the same `requests.get()` after 5 seconds?
The timeout argument ends the program itself if connection is timed out over 5 seconds.

```
page2 = requests.get(url, timeout=5.000)
```

Comment: You can look into overriding the http request adapter. The docs talk about a Retry object that you can setup into the session. Or you can just retry in an outer python loop..as many times as you wish. Is that ok?

Comment: But how do I stop the program from ending if the request times out?

Comment: You can run the `.get()` inside of a `try-except` block where the exception is `requests.TimeoutError`, I believe. Then in that little section just run `pass`.

Comment: I'm trying this and it isn't working     try:
        page2 = requests.get(url)
    except requests.Timeout:
        pass

Comment: You will still need to set `timeout=5` on the request, otherwise it will wait forever.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your's problem is that the `requests.get` doesn't wait enough time, you can set the `timeout` argument to more then 5 seconds.

If not, as @jheld mention, you can take the approach of the `try-except`, like this:

```
response = None
try:
    response = requests.get(SITE_URL, timeout=5)
except requests.exceptions.Timeout:
    try:
        response = requests.get(SITE_URL, timeout=5)
    except requests.exceptions.Timeout:
        pass
```

Comment: Solved based on @jheld inputs. I did not need the timeout parameter though. Many thanks jheld and yuval

Comment: If you found this answer helpful, please accept it for future users to learn from this answer @babsdoc

Answer (score 0):

Probably too late to answer this question. But for anybody searching for a more reliable solution:

#### Code

```py
retry_times = 5
for count in range(retry_times+1):
            try:
                response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, timeout=10)
                code = response.status_code
                if response.status_code == 200:
                    break
            except requests.exceptions.Timeout:
                print(f"Trying again {count}/{retry_times}....")
# Do whatever you want here
print(response.status_code)
```

#### Output

```
Trying again 1/5....
Trying again 2/5....
200
```